# Is this authentic if so how is this justified?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, sahaba

Ibn Kathir records:

“Ibn Asakir has narrated under the events of Muawiyah’s slave Khadij al Hazi that Muawiyah bought a fair complexioned and beautiful slave-girl and he (Khadij) undressed her and brought her before Muawiyah, he was carrying a stick in his hand and began bowing towards her vagina and said: “I wish this vagina was for me; take her to Yazeed bin Muawyah.” He then said “No! Call Rabi’ bin Umro al Qarshi”. He (Rabi) was a jurist (Faqih). When he came, Muawiyah asked him: “This slave-girl has been brought before me in a naked condition and I have seen her here and there, I want to send her to Yazeed”. He said: “O commander of faithful! Don’t do this. This is inappropriate”. Muawiyah said: “Your suggestion is correct”. The narrator says that Muawiyah then gifted her to the servant of Fatima, daughter of Holy Prophet [s] namely Abdullah bin Mas’adat Fazari who was black and Muawiyah told him: “Make your children white through her”.

Al Badayah wal Niahayh (Urdu), Vol 8 page 992 ‘Wives and sons of Muawyah’ published by Nafees Academy Karachi.

If this is true that means muawiyah allowed Khadij al hazi to see a woman he does not own in her private areas. How is this justified?

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

Khadij\Hadij was an eunuch. Further I don't see any evidence that he saw the female's private part or even that he saw her naked. Rather he told her to enter upon Muawiyah naked.

And it was Muawiyah who saw her private parts (which was permissible for him because he owned her). And this was the reason why he hesitated and was advised to not gift the concubine to his son Yazeed, because that would be a form of incest, as a lustful glance is considered by some madhabs as being enough to fulfill the criterion of [4:22](https://quran.com/4/22?translations=20):

> فتحرج أن يهبها من ولده يزيد لقوله تعالى: * (ولا تنكحوا ما نكح آباؤكم من النساء) * [النساء: ٢٢] وقد وافقه على ذلك الفقيه ربيعة بن عمرو الجرشي الدمشقي
>
> <sup>— [Al-Bidaya wa'l-Nihaya](https://shamela.ws/book/8376/3000)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer